# Unable to fetch array response from json object in typescript

Tags: json, typescript, angular5

I'm currently working on google's dialog flow using api-ai-javascript. I'm recieving a response from server in json format and trying to access "res.result.fulfillment.messages[0]" field in it. But everytime i "ng serve" it displays following error: "error TS2339: Property 'messages' does not exist on type '{ speech: string; }'". I tried to display the whole response in console, and it shows "messages" field. Can someone plz help [here's screenshot of my console log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZoiX4.png)

Comment: res.result.fulfillment.messages[0].speech

Comment: access single element using above statement.

Comment: did not work. shows same error again :(

Comment: post your response json here http://snippi.com

Comment: sorry for the delayed response. here, this is the response: http://snippi.com/s/v83e1r7

Comment: I'm fetching field in html with same query, it is successfully showing the expected results. But on ng serve / ng build it still shows the same error in CLI. I've to deploy the app and because of this error, I'm not being able to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. In my case, this was related to api-ai-javascript. In 'interfaces.ts', IserverResponse interface only had 'speech' in 'fulfillment' tag. Adding "messages?: any[];" to it, fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like object only have property speech. You should try to get speech against message.

Like that: response.speech or console.log(response) to see all the object.

Comment: thanks Jose, but I already include the image link of console.log(response)

Comment: Ok, i only see two properties in your response. type and speech. Looks like speech is your string no?